# Windows ffmpeg hardware accelerated video encoding FAILS using codec hevc_amf but works with codec h264_amf

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, hardware-acceleration, h.265

I'm running `ffmpeg` on Windows 10 on a machine with an AMD Radion HD 7700.  Hardware accelerated h.264 works fine while HEVC encoding fails.  The version of `ffmpeg` is:

```
ffmpeg version 5.1.2-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.1.0 (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      57. 28.100 / 57. 28.100
libavcodec     59. 37.100 / 59. 37.100
libavformat    59. 27.100 / 59. 27.100
libavdevice    59.  7.100 / 59.  7.100
libavfilter     8. 44.100 /  8. 44.100
libswscale      6.  7.100 /  6.  7.100
libswresample   4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
libpostproc    56.  6.100 / 56.  6.100
```

Why does this command work:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i "E:\Ripped MKVs\Duel\Duel_t01.mkv" -map 0:v -c:v h264_amf -y "E:\Processed Videos\Duel.mkv"
```

while this one fails:

```
ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -i "E:\Ripped MKVs\Duel\Duel_t01.mkv" -map 0:v -c:v hevc_amf -y "E:\Processed Videos\Duel.mkv"
```

Here's the error:

```
[hevc_amf @ 000002c4def2b780] CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderHW_HEVC) failed with error 10
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in this area, but here is my answer to the question I asked, based on empirical evidence using multiple graphics cards:

It would appear that when `ffmpeg` uses a software codec, all of the encoding is done by the codec.  On the other hand, when a hardware codec is specified (i.e. `-c:v hevc_amf` instead of `-c:v hevc`) then the codec really isn't doing any encoding at all.  Instead, it is a wrapper around the "real" codec, implemented on the graphics card.  If the graphics card doesn't support the method of encoding that the specified codec calls for, then you will get the error I received:

```
[hevc_amf @ 000002c4def2b780] CreateComponent(AMFVideoEncoderHW_HEVC) failed with error 10
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

The following information may help you.  I think this is "mostly" correct:

There are 3 GPU manufacturers: AMD, NVIDIA and Intel.  AMD and NVIDIA sell the GPUs to graphic card manufacturers.  For example, I have VisionTek graphics card.  This card has an AMD GPU, so when deciding what codec to use, you only care about the fact that the card has an AMD GPU.  Another example, I also have an EVGA GeForce GTX 1650 graphics card.  While made by EVGA, it has the NVIDIA GPU (which of course will be the NVIDIA GeForce 1650 GPU).  The Intel GPU is build into many of Intel's CPU product line (but not all).

Both AMD and Nvidia publish specifications for the specific GPU a graphics card might use.  These specifications state which video codecs are support.  So if you know you want to be able to do HEVC encoding, for example, you can verify that a video card will support the type of HEVC encoding you want to perform.